# setInterval in React to update customised clock every 1 second encounter distorted in render in Safari latest vesrion

Tags: reactjs, safari

So I'm making a "timelapse" clock with fixed starting hour. So, it starts from 8 o'clock to 18 o'clock then repeat. every 4 seconds, 1 hour will be passed. Any other suggestions on improving my code also really help me. Thank you in advance.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        minute: 0,
        second: 0,
        hour: 8,
        leadingZero: 0
    };
}
 componentDidMount() {
    this.timerClock = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.state.minute < 45 && this.state.hour <= 17) {
            this.setState({
                minute: this.state.minute + 15
            })
        }
        else if (this.state.minute >= 45 && this.state.hour <= 17) {

            this.setState({
                minute: 0,
                hour: this.state.hour + 1
            })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                minute: 15,
                hour: 8,
            })
        }
    }, 1000);


}


componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerClock);

}
 render() {
    return (
        <p className="timelapse--clockTime">{this.state.hour < 10 && this.state.leadingZero}{this.state.hour}:{this.state.minute < 10 && this.state.leadingZero}{this.state.minute}
        </p>
    );
}
```

So the clock updates as I want, but on Safari, sometimes it renders new state quite distorted.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The *setInterval* call will place your function in the callback queue for a timer but it's not guaranteed to hit the interval that you specify with great precision.**

Each JS engine implementation in each browser varies in how it implements the timers but most will probably have some sort of pooling of timer callbacks which means that it's hard to predict the exact variation between the desired interval and the actual interval between calls to your callback function.

And the resolution gets worse when you get down to the tens of milliseconds level.

So you really cant rely on the fact that the sum of the intervals will correspond to desired time.

About your render, this is strange. Seems that you have 2 renders that overlap each other but in your code I don't find the evidence of this.

If you provide a working snippet reproducing the problem I can be more precise.

Comment: I indeed have three setInterval functions running at the same time in three components. The first component is the clock which has setInterval for 1 second, the second and third component are the image and the chart which has interval for 4 seconds.  So should I use recurrsion setTimeout for this ?

Comment: The problem is not recursion, the important issue that you cant rely on N update in   span of time. The best way is to trigger the function with the timing you like and make calculation based on current Date() timestamp. Doing so you can be sure to have the right time each iteration, even if the iteration has implicit delay.